# urllib2: Indexing several keywords

Tags: indexing, python-2.7, urllib2

I've been looking around for a while and i can't seem to find guides on using the index command from urllib2. 
Basically the function finds the first word which is/or contains the characters the index function is given and then returns the position of it.

```
page_content= urllib2.urlopen(URL).read() #Gets the website
i1 = page_content.index(keyword) #finds keyword in the website
```

And from here on i1 can be used for different things in the urllib2, but that's not relevant to this.

My problem is that .index does not get ALL words matching the keyword, but only the first. Which is no problem if you know there is only one of the kind on the website, but i would like to get all of them assigned to a list which i could then take their positions from and use.

Answer (score 0):

user re function

```
import re 
page_content= urllib2.urlopen(URL).read() #Gets the website
idall = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(keyword,page_content)]

print idall
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly once i got my code changed to get all the values from the idall. Thank you.